# conditional subtraction in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following data frame.

```
ID Year    
A 2001
A 2002
A 2003
B 2009
B 2010
```

I would like to create a third column in which I substract the minimum year of the corresponding ID to the year and then add one.

In short, I would like to have this:

```
ID Year New   
A 2001 1
A 2002 2
A 2003 3
B 2009 1
B 2010 2
```

I am pretty new to R and dplyr and havent found the way to do that without a loop..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Since you're using `dplyr` I'd take a look at the `group_by` and `mutate` functions.  `group_by` will break your data frame into groups on which the calls in `mutate` will act independently.

Comment: In base R, `df$New <- ave(df$Year, df$ID, FUN=seq_along)` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr` you need to use `group_by` and `mutate` like so:

```
df <-  read.table(text = "ID Year    
                          A 2001
                          A 2002
                          A 2003
                          B 2009
                          B 2010", header = T)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(New = Year - min(Year) + 1)
df

# ID  Year   New
#  A  2001     1
#  A  2002     2
#  A  2003     3
#  B  2009     1
#  B  2010     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tribble(~ID, ~year,
"A", 2001,
"A", 2002,
"A", 2003,
"B", 2009,
"B", 2010
)
data %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(new = year - min(year)+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ddply`:

```
library(plyr)
df<-data.frame(ID=c("A","A","A","B","B"), Year=c(2001,2002,2003,2009,2010))

ddply(df, .(ID), transform, New=Year-min(Year)+1)
```